# Populate MySQL table with data from other MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, union

I would like to create a table that populates its data from other tables through SQL queries. For example:

> Create TABLE1 with columns (AVERAGE_ROWS int, AVERAGE_RATING int)
>
> > Insert into TABLE1 values (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE X, SELECT AVG(rating) FROM TABLE X)
> >
> > > Insert into TABLE1 values (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE Y, SELECT AVG(rating) FROM TABLE Y)

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance, el retardo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to follow the format:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1;
```

So in your case it would look something like ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ee77e/2/1)):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (AVERAGE_ROWS, AVERAGE_RATING)
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(rating) FROM X
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(rating) FROM Y;
```

As you can see in the example you are going to lose your presion on `AVG(rating)` since `AVERAGE_RATING` is declared as `int`.  You would be better off using `decimal(,)` instead.  Something like [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69ca7e3/2/1).

Comment: Thank you, this has got me on the right track. I created the holding table ("table1" for this purpose) and populated the data from tables X & Y with the queries.
`INSERT INTO table1(AVERAGE_ROWS, AVERAGE RATING)
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(rating) FROM X
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(rating) FROM Y;`

However, when table X or Y is modified post table1 creation, the updated data is not being referenced in table1 on a `select *` Any help?

Comment: That is not how it works.  The INSERT statement only works when you run it.  Do you really need `table1`.  Why not just execute a SELECT statment to get what you need when you need it.  Otherwise you are probably looking at creating a trigger to update `table1` when something happens to the other tables, which seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: My problem lies with JSON, ANDROID & PHP. I'm trying to populate a listview from a JSON array. But I'm struggling (with my limited skills and expertise). I thank you for your help though, I think I need to move over onto a new subject! :)